# Color code specific column in tableau on mac laptop

Tags: tableau-api, conditional-formatting

I have just shifted to a mac laptop and I want to color code a specific column based on its value, I was able to do this on a windows laptop by pressing ctrl + measure and dragging it to the colors mark. When I try doing command + measure and drag it to the colors mark then the conditional formatting changes for the entire table.

How do i do this in mac?

Tableau desktop version : 2019.2.3

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `Measure Names` and put it in the color palate.
2. Filter out the column you want to color code.